# How can i insert a variable in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

im noob in Python and i want to connect a database(sqlite3) with my "account manager", and so i want to insert a variable in read_from_db, instead of a word. Can someone help me?

```
def read_from_db():
    **c.execute("SELECT * FROM daten WHERE username= AND password= ")**
    # data = c.fetchall()
    for row in c.fetchall():
        name_test = (row[0])
        password_test = (row[1])
```

Comment: You didn't mentined what's your problem here. The code you provided doesn't insert a variable, but fetches records instead. Perhaps it worth starting from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3)?

Answer (score 1):

If use python 3.6+, check out [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```
def read_from_db(un, pw):
    **c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM daten WHERE username={un} AND password={pw} ")**
    # data = c.fetchall()
    for row in c.fetchall():
        name_test = (row[0])
        password_test = (row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way is to use `.format()`

```
def read_from_db(p):
    **c.execute("SELECT * FROM daten WHERE username={0} AND password={1}".format(user_name, password)**
    # data = c.fetchall()
    for row in c.fetchall():
        name_test = (row[0])
        password_test = (row[1])
```

Comment: in the debuggin console it writes no such column?